# Pjsip video decoding issue on iOS

Tags: ios, video, decoding, pjsip

My application implements sip video calls with pjsip 2.9. I use `pjsua_call_set_vid_strm(call_id, op, &param)` function to enable video on incoming call. Then a can see incoming video for about 20 seconds with significant delay, which is growing up to 5 seconds. And after all video get lost. Sometimes I can see the green screen when video starts. There are some errors in log. Looks like pjsip can't allocate enough buffer for decoding video frames. Why is that?
Here are some log records with errors:

```
v=0
s=Asterisk PBX 13.14.1
b=CT:1024
t=0 0
m=audio 11088 RTP/AVP 0 98
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:98 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:98 0-16
a=maxptime:150
a=sendrecv
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 31
m=video 12180 RTP/AVP 99
a=rtpmap:99 H264/90000
a=fmtp:99 profile-level-id=42E01E
a=sendrecv
...
12:28:33.712          vid_toolbox.m  .Decode couldn't produce picture, input nframes=2, concatenated size=2256 bytes
...
12:28:33.942      vstenc0x11007fa28 !Forcing encoder to generate keyframe
...
12:28:35.537      vstdec0x11007fa28  Error: not enough buffer for decoded frame (supplied=645504, required=1721344)
12:28:35.542          vid_toolbox.m !.Frame size changed to 704x576
12:28:35.556        strm0x10a99d028 !Jitter buffer starts returning normal frames (after 1 empty/lost)
12:28:35.570      vstdec0x11007fa28 ! Decoding format changed: 704x576 I420<- 15/1(~15)fps
12:28:35.570       ios_opengl_dev.c  Stopping ios opengl stream
12:28:35.570       ios_opengl_dev.c  Starting ios opengl stream
12:28:35.570      vstdec0x11007fa28  Error: not enough buffer for decoded frame (supplied=645504, required=1721344)
...
12:28:35.803       ios_opengl_dev.c  Stopping ios opengl stream
12:28:35.804       ios_opengl_dev.c  Starting ios opengl stream
12:28:35.804      vstdec0x11007fa28  Error: not enough buffer for decoded frame (supplied=645504, required=1721344)
12:28:35.814          vid_toolbox.m !.Frame size changed to 704x576
12:28:35.853      vstdec0x11007fa28 ! Decoding format changed: 704x576 I420<- 15/1(~15)fps
12:28:35.853       ios_opengl_dev.c  Stopping ios opengl stream
12:28:35.853       ios_opengl_dev.c  Starting ios opengl stream
...
12:28:37.268          vid_toolbox.m  Unpacketize error: Ignored (PJ_EIGNORED)
12:28:37.268          vid_toolbox.m  Decoding buffer overflow or unpacketize error size: 0, buffer: 1441200
12:28:37.268          vid_toolbox.m  Decode couldn't produce picture, input nframes=1, concatenated size=0 bytes
```

Can anybody help my? How can I increase decoder buffer size?

Comment: Please try with lower resolution and check the network packets that are received.

Comment: I tried to set different profile-level-id, sometimes it changes supplied/required values, but still not enough :(

Comment: Can you share the wireshark logs or pcap file.

Comment: Can you change the codec? I have the same error when I use VideoToolBox as the codec. No error occurred since I changed the codec to OpenH264(Latest version V2.1.1)